# Filtering on relate using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, relates

I've created a relate in ArcGIS Pro - joined a shape layer to a table on a key. ArcGIS Pro says it has gone through okay, and when I click on a feature I can go down into the information displayed and see the relate (though I can't see the related data, just the relate taking place).

How can I filter on this? I can't find the option anywhere to filter on a relate and, when I look at the definition query, it only has the options from the selected table (i.e. the shape).

---

I can see the related data now, I'd linked it up the wrong way. I still need to filter on it somehow.

---

It turns out that doing a JOIN will do the job (I thought it would simply take one set of data and add it to another, but both sets of data seem to remain separate - I can update them at source and they'll reflect their changes).

Comment: I think you are out of luck here. Standalone tables do not support definition query. I usually extract data from relate and join it to feature class